# Интерполяция RigidBody 2D в старом Unity Network

Tags: unity3d, сеть, 2d, интерполяция

Как правильно сделать интерполяцию игроков с RigidBody 2D? Мне нужно, чтобы игроки могли толкать друг друга, а сейчас они проходят сквозь друг друга, так как я сделал интерполяцию через transform. Дело в том, что если я поменяю интерполяцию через transform.position на rigidbody.position, то игроки начинают тормозить, когда перемещаются рядом со стенкой и после столкновения передают неправильную позицию (SynEndPos). Я не знаю как это исправить.

На префабе игрока Box Collider 2D, RigidBody 2D, NetworkView (следит за скриптом).

Код:

```
// Это в Update
if (netView.isMine) {...}
else
// Интерполяция
    {
        SynTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SynStartPos, SynEndPos, SynTime / SynDelay);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(SynStartAngle, SynEndAngle, SynTime / SynDelay);
    }



// Синхронизация
void OnSerializeNetworkView(BitStream stream, NetworkMessageInfo info)
{
    Vector3 SynPos = Vector3.zero;
    Quaternion SynAngle = Quaternion.identity;

    if (!stream.isWriting)
    {
        // Чтение
        stream.Serialize(ref SynPos);
        stream.Serialize(ref SynAngle);

        // Расчеты для интерполяции
        SynTime = 0;
        SynDelay = Time.time - LastSynTime;
        LastSynTime = Time.time;

        SynStartPos = transform.position;
        SynEndPos = SynPos;

        SynStartAngle = transform.rotation;
        SynEndAngle = SynAngle;
    }
    else
    {
        // Запись
        SynPos = transform.position;
        stream.Serialize(ref SynPos);

        SynAngle = transform.rotation;
        stream.Serialize(ref SynAngle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я еще додумался синхронить rigidbody.velocity, но хоть игроки и толкают друг друга немного, все равно "проваливаются" в друг друга (Collision Detection стоит на Continuous).

Comment: Эта тема одна из самых сложных и спорных в unity, но есть уже готовое рабочее free-licence решение: [ссылка на проект](http://unity3ddd.ru/unity/assety/1921-unet-authoritative-networking.html) – Я не призываю копипастить код, этот проект создан в целях обучения, изучив его, думаю тебе сразу станет все понятно и ты сможешь решить проблему с интерполяцией.